# Pinescript configure style of pricelables in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I wrote a pine indicator for TradingView. The indicator shows 8 Moving averages. Is it possible to hide the price Labels of every moving average on the Pricescala and if yes how.

Thank you and best regards

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(smaCus20,title="SMA20",color = color.green,linewidth = 2,display=display.pane)
```

Use display=display.pane